# How to ignore NaN in rolling average calculation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, nan

For a time series sales forecasting task I want to create a feature that represents the average sales over the last 3 days. I have a problem when I want to predict the sales for days in the future, since these data points do not have sales data (NaN values). Pandas offers rolling_mean(), but that function results in a NaN ouput when any data point in the window is NaN.

My data:

```
Date    Sales
02-01-2013  100.0
03-01-2013  200.0
04-01-2013  300.0
05-01-2013  200.0
06-01-2013  NaN
```

Result after using pd.rolling_mean() with window of 2:

```
Date    Rolling_Sales
02-01-2013  NaN
03-01-2013  150.0
04-01-2013  250.0
05-01-2013  250.0
06-01-2013  NaN
```

Desired result:

```
Date    Rolling_Sales
02-01-2013  NaN
03-01-2013  150.0
04-01-2013  250.0
05-01-2013  250.0
06-01-2013  200.0
```

So in case the a NaN is included, I want to ignore it and take the average of all the other data points in the window.

Comment: Are you looking for df.ffill().Sales.rolling(2).mean()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is on way adding `min_periods`

```
s=df.Sales.rolling(window=2,min_periods=1).mean()
s.iloc[0]=np.nan
s
Out[1293]: 
0      NaN
1    150.0
2    250.0
3    250.0
4    200.0
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This does not address the problem. You're assuming the NaNs result at the beginning of the window, but there appears to be a bug in pandas... you can't ignore/skip nan values that occur later in the series as well.

min_periods shows up everywhere as an answer to this. It IS NOT the answer.

Comment: @user5747140 so what is the answer?

Comment: This might not be the best answer, but what I have done partly in response to @user5747140 point is to us df.fillna(method='ffill') before using rolling. This might not work for all and depends on your data, but for my purposes forward filling to remove nan values was acceptable practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what OP is going for here. Here is why the above answer is NOT correct. Problem description: we want to compute a rolling function (mean, median, sum, etc) that behaves similarly to `np.nan[function]` while retaining the ability to have `W` nans at the start of the result due to a window length not being long enough.

The above answer with `min_periods` invalidates the behavior of having `nan` where the window is not long enough. However, pandas `rolling` does not provide the ability to allow `nan` in rolling window (of the correct length) to be viewed as a "valid" sample. Here is the required logic:

If (current window length < desired window length) -> return `nan`

If (current window length == desired window length) -> return `np.nan[func](window)`

I've seen a few questions like this across stack overflow and the problem is hard to describe, so a lot of people do not have the correct answer. Here is a solution using `numba` and using a rolling sum as an example. In my example, I am also providing the ability to not calculate the function over the first block of `nan` if such a block exists. Remove `A` from this to remove this functionality:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np
@njit
def rolling_nansum(x, W):
    # Setup Output Array
    out = np.full(len(x), np.nan)

    # Find the First non-nan value (virst valid sample for the function)
    A = (~np.isnan(x)).argmax()

    # Compute the Rolling Function
    for i in range(A+W-1, len(x)):
        out[i] = np.nansum(x[i-W+1:i+1])
    return out

df.apply(lambda x: rolling_nansum(x, 100), raw=True, axis=0)
```

This was tested on a 4300x1000 element DataFrame and performs the calculation in `480 ms`.

This code applies the correct logic, columnwise across the DataFrame. This is a good way to handle rolling functions on missing data without introducing lookahead bias, or having results with `nan`. This is a common use case for financial data.